# How to delete a table row using a separate button in js

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

So I am creating a table where I need to be able to delete a row when I focus on the input field inside a cell using a button outside the table

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="remove_row" role="button" onclick="removeRow()">
  <span>Remove</span>
</div>
<table id="ListTab" role="grid">
  <thead tabindex="0">
    <tr role="row">
      <th title="Column 1" role="columnheader">
        <span>Column 1</span>
      </th>
      <th title="Column 2" role="columnheader">
        <span>Column 2</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody tabindex="0">
    <tr class="UiListRow">
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="UiListRow">
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="UiListRow">
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want when the user stand on one of the inputs and clicks remove it only removes that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```js
var currentFocus = null;

document.querySelector('table').addEventListener("focusin", focusChanged);

function focusChanged(event) {
  currentFocus = event.target;
}

function removeRow() {
  if (currentFocus == null) {
    return;
  }
  var rowToRemove = currentFocus.closest('tr');
  if (rowToRemove.parentElement == null) {
    return;
  }
  rowToRemove.parentElement.removeChild(rowToRemove);
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="remove_row" role="button" onclick="removeRow()">
  <span>Remove</span>
</div>
<table id="ListTab" role="grid">
  <thead tabindex="0">
    <tr role="row">
      <th title="Column 1" role="columnheader">
        <span>Column 1</span>
      </th>
      <th title="Column 2" role="columnheader">
        <span>Column 2</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody tabindex="0">
    <tr class="UiListRow">
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="a">
      </td>
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="UiListRow">
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="b">
      </td>
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="UiListRow">
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="c">
      </td>
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have an add row function and when a new row is added it doesn't detect if it is focused so it can't delete

Comment: I changed the "focus" listener on each input item to a "focusin" listener on the table. Does that work for you?

Comment: It is generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative: use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to handle Adding/Removal of rows.

```js
[`click`, `focusin`].forEach(et => document.addEventListener(et, handle));
const deactivateAllRows = () => document.querySelectorAll(`#ListTab td.active`)
  .forEach(td => td.classList.replace(`active`, `inactive`));

function handle(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;

  if (evt.type === `click`) {
    if (origin.id === `addRow`) { return addRow(); }

    if (origin.closest(`td`) &&
      origin.closest(`td`).classList.contains(`active`)
    ) {   return origin.closest(`tr`).remove();  }
  }

  if (evt.type === `focusin` &&
    origin.type === `text` &&
    origin.closest(`tr`)) {
    deactivateAllRows();
    const shouldDeactivate = origin.closest(`tr`).querySelector(`td.inactive`);
    return shouldDeactivate &&
      shouldDeactivate.classList.replace(`inactive`, `active`);
  }

  return true;
}

function addRow() {
  deactivateAllRows();
  document.querySelector(`#ListTab tbody`)
    .insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`,
      document.querySelector(`#ListTab tbody tr`).outerHTML);
}
```

```css
.inactive {
  color: #EEE;
}

.active {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="addRow">Add row</button>

<table id="ListTab" role="grid">
  <thead tabindex="0">
    <tr role="row">
      <th title="Column 1" role="columnheader">
        <span>Column 1</span>
      </th>
      <th title="Column 2" role="columnheader">
        <span>Column 2</span>
      </th>
      <th title="remove" role="columnheader" id="removeHeader">
        <span>Remove row</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody tabindex="0">
    <tr class="UiListRow">
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="inactive">
        Remove
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="UiListRow">
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="inactive">
        Remove
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="UiListRow">
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="inactive">
        Remove
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```